# How to create two lines and scatter plots using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, line-plot

I have the following data in R:

```
id <- factor(seq(1:72))
initial.e <- rnorm(n=72, mean = 21.51, sd = 6.58)
initial.f <- rnorm(n = 72, mean = 20.75, sd = 3.378)

final.e <- rnorm(n = 72, mean = 19.81, sd = 7.48)
final.f <- rnorm(n = 72, mean = 19.77, sd = 5.389)

data <- data.frame(id,initial.e, initial.f, final.e, final.f)
```

I need to create a scatter plot with two straight trendlines for `e` and `f`, but I'm lost on how to create that. I found this article: https://sakaluk.wordpress.com/2015/08/27/6-make-it-pretty-plotting-2-way-interactions-with-ggplot2/ which I tried following, but didn't work the way I wanted.

I also tried using `melt` from `reshape2` package, but I can't get the plots to show the way I want to - with two trendlines for `e` and `f` in the scatter plot.

```
datamelt <- melt(data, id = 'id')
datamelt <- datamelt %>% mutate(names = ifelse(datamelt$variable %in% c('initial.e', 'initial.f'), 'Before', 'After'))

datamelt <- datamelt %>% mutate(types = ifelse(datamelt$variable %in% c('final.e', 'final.f'), 'e', 'f'))
```

After this things went downhill. All the codes I tried either have some basic scatter plot with `geom_smooth()` or just some generic error.

**EDIT**

The plot should contain scatterplot containing relationship between `intial.e` and `initial.f` with a trend line, and another relationship between `final.e` and `final.f` with a trend line in the same plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
data %>%
    gather(k, value, -id) %>%
    mutate(
        state = gsub("(\\.e$|\\.f$)", "", k),
        what = gsub("(initial\\.|final\\.)", "", k)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(id, value, colour = what)) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_wrap(~ state)
```

[image]

Or with points

```
data %>%
    gather(k, value, -id) %>%
    mutate(
        state = gsub("(\\.e$|\\.f$)", "", k),
        what = gsub("(initial\\.|final\\.)", "", k)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(id, value, colour = what)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() + 
    facet_wrap(~ state)
```

[image]

---

### Update

```
data %>%
    gather(k, value, -id) %>%
    mutate(
        state = gsub("(\\.e$|\\.f$)", "", k),
        what = gsub("(initial\\.|final\\.)", "", k)) %>%
    select(-k) %>%
    spread(state, value) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = initial, y = final, colour = what, fill = what)) +
    geom_smooth(fullrange = T, method = "lm") +
    geom_point()
```

[image]

We're showing a trend-line based on a simple linear regression `lm`, including confidence band (disable with `se = F` inside `geom_smooth`). You could also show a LOESS trend with `method = loess` inside `geom_smooth`. See `?geom_smooth` for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I think I also got the same result, but this is not what I was looking for. If you look at the site I referenced, they have two straight lines showing the trend. That's what I was trying to produce with this data. I edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: This is great! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is something like this: I haven't tested the code, but it should give you an idea

```
ggplot(data) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=initial.e, y=initial.f)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, aes(initial.e, final.e)) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=final.e, y = final.f)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, aes(final.e, final.f))
```